# Windows 10 not detected after running boot repair

Tags: grub2

I had broken my Ubuntu grub, so I attempted to run boot-repair to fix it. Ubuntu now is able to login, but Windows 10 no longer shows up. I've tried most of the solutions found online, such as editing the grub file, but it does not work. Here is my pastebin:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/k4mCs2z4HQ/

os-prober actually detects Windows:

```
/dev/sda1:Windows 10 (loader):Windows:chain
/dev/sda2:Windows 10 (loader):Windows1:chain
```

Comment: It says this in script: "The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume"  http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions  Grub only boots working Windows or Windows that is not hibernated nor needs chkdsk. You have to directly boot Windows or use your Windows repair disk's repair console. Boot-Repair can temporarily add Windows boot loader.https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader

Comment: @oldfred great answer!